# 1С-Битрикс: сайт на поддомене

Tags: домен, php, битрикс

Доброго дня. Как всегда, есть проблема.
У сайта site.ru есть поддомен lk.site.ru. Физически они раположены в папках /www/site.ru/ и /www/lk.site.ru/. На site.ru стоит старенький 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 9.0.2, а на lk.site.ru нет вообще ничего. Каким образом можно заставить оба сайта работать c одной админкой?
Заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено**
Воспользовался указаниями http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/howto/336.php: создал симлинки, скопировал access и index, прописал в админке хосты и папки, однако `CMainPage::GetSiteByHost();` на lk.site.ru показывает id сайта site.ru. Что, в общем-то, логично: ибо поддомен. Как побороть эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут - [многосайтовость на пальцах](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/howto/336.php) - про это подробно расписано. Только я не совсем понял, будет ли это работать с поддоменами. Посмотрите, может поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. =)

Comment: Добавил к ответу.

Comment: Поковырялся в настройках. Теперь все работает, хотя SITE_ID все равно один на всех.